# JavaScript Border Height Function--Match Two Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure this was raised before, but haven't come across a sufficient answer on the web.

My `index` page contains two columns that are visually, and equally divided by a vertical line (border). To implement this, I used the `border-right`property on the first (left) column.

How do I write a JS function that *always* matches the border height for the two columns?

Update: I'm using css `nth-child` `1` and `2` for the two columns.

Update 2: how about something like that?

```
function getHeight(class) {
    return document.getElementByClass(class).offsetHeight;
}

var maxHeight = Math.max( getHeight( "article:nth-child(odd)" ), getHeight( "article:nth-child(even)" );

var nOdd = document.getElementByClass( "article:nth-child(odd)" );
var nEven = document.getElementByClass( "article:nth-child(even)" );

nOdd.style.height = maxHeight;
nEven.style.height = maxHeight;
```

Comment: `$('#col2').height($('#col1').height())` means `col2` will have the same height as `col1` however it depends entire on the content inside both col2 and 1.

Comment: Seeing that you tagged this with jQuery, I'm assuming you're using it. Use jQuery to select both columns and compare their heights. Then set the smaller height to the same height as the larger column.

Comment: @Praveen--This works as long as the two columns are static. However, when their length is extended (JS animation), the same height is not kept.

Comment: If you change the length of one of the columns, then obviously you will need to recalculate.

Comment: I'll look into that. Could you show me an example function in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a css only solution:

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/2d581dd1a877ccdea7d32eb9e40f48a8)

css

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
section {
  flex: 1;

}
section:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus sum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus assumenda tempore, obcaecati similique mollitia, ipsa dolorum nihil  dolor </section>
  <section>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus assumenda tempore, obcaecati similique mollitia, ipsa dolorum nihil placeat maiores eius cupiditate ipsam harum recusandae, quia accusamus. Quae a illo, amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus assumenda tempore, obcaecati similique mollitia, ipsa dolorum nihil placeat maiores eius cupiditate ipsam harum recusandae, quia accusamus. Quae a illo, amet.
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getBorderHeight(){
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('.border')[0];
    var c_height = el.style.height;
    var b_height = el.style.borderWidth;
    return c_height+b_height*2;
}
```

Comment: What is use of border width property here.  The above code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what this does and how it helps with the original question?

Answer (score -2):

This is not a Javascript only solution, but it's a CSS only solution...

Use the CSS `background` property.

Create a 1x1 pic and repeat for parent container.

Comment: ??  I think the question is not related to background